# Run celery task when testing (pytest) in Django

Tags: django, pytest, celery

I have three Celery tasks:

```
@celery_app.task
def load_rawdata_on_monday():
    if not load_rawdata():  # run synchronously
        notify_report_was_not_updated.delay()


@celery_app.task
def load_rawdata():
    # load and process file from FTP
    return False  # some error happened


@celery_app.task
def notify_rawdata_was_not_updated():
    pass  # send email by Django
```

I need to test that email was sent if `load_rawdata` task (function) returns `False`. For that I have written some test which does not work:

```
@override_settings(EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.memcache.EmailBackend')
@override_settings(CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=False)
@patch('load_rawdata', MagicMock(return_value=False))
def test_load_rawdata_on_monday():
    load_rawdata_on_monday()
    assert len(mail.outbox) == 1, "Inbox is not empty"
    assert mail.outbox[0].subject == 'Subject here'
    assert mail.outbox[0].body == 'Here is the message.'
    assert mail.outbox[0].from_email == 'from@example.com'
    assert mail.outbox[0].to == ['to@example.com']
```

It seems `notify_rawdata_was_not_updated` still being run asynchronously.
How to write proper test?

Comment: `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should'v use `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER` instead of `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like two things may be happening:

- You should call your task with using the `apply()` [method](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply) to run it synchronously.
- The `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` [setting](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/3.1/configuration.html#celery-always-eager) should be active to allow subsequent task calls to be executed as well.

```py
@override_settings(EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.memcache.EmailBackend')
@override_settings(CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True)
@patch('load_rawdata', MagicMock(return_value=False))
def test_load_rawdata_on_monday():
    load_rawdata_on_monday.apply()
    assert len(mail.outbox) == 1, "Inbox is not empty"
    assert mail.outbox[0].subject == 'Subject here'
    assert mail.outbox[0].body == 'Here is the message.'
    assert mail.outbox[0].from_email == 'from@example.com'
    assert mail.outbox[0].to == ['to@example.com']
```

Comment: the code you provided does not use @patch decorator to mock the `notify_rawdata_was_not_updated `task.
This means that the real `notify_rawdata_was_not_updated` task will be run during the test, and you will not be able to make assertions about how it was called.

Answer (score 2):

While @tinom9 is correct about using the `apply()` method, the issue of `notify_rawdata_was_not_updated` still running asynchronously has to do with your task definition:

```
@celery_app.task
def load_rawdata_on_monday():
    if not load_rawdata():  
        notify_report_was_not_updated.delay() # delay is an async invocation
```

try this:

```
@celery_app.task
def load_rawdata_on_monday():
    if not load_rawdata():  
        notify_report_was_not_updated.apply() # run on local thread
```

and for the test, calling `load_rawdata_on_monday()` without `.delay()` or `.apply()` should still execute the task locally and block until the task result returns. Just make sure you are handling the return values correctly, some celery invocation methods, like `apply()` return an [celery.result.EagerResult](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.EagerResult) instance compared to `delay()` or `apply_async()` which return an [celery.result.AsyncResult](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult) instance, which may not give you the desired outcome if expecting `False` when you check `if not load_rawdata()`
or anywhere else you try to get the return value of the function and not the task itself.